# Strange result in simple LPC simulation of a sinus

Tags: matlab, filters, linear-prediction, lpc

I'm trying to understand how [Matlab LPC function](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/lpc.html) works. So I made a little example script : I generate a real cosinus, calculate the LPC coefficients of this signal and then I try to predict the signal using only its first samples of it.

```
clear all;

%% Configuration

Fs = 1e4; % Sampling frequency
F = 1054; % Signal frequency
order = 128; % LPC order

%% Generate signal
t = 0:1/Fs:1 - 1/Fs; 
t = t.';

ft = exp(2*1i*pi*F*t);
ft = real(ft);

[a, g] = lpc(ft, order);

%% Apply LPC filter
samples = ft(1:order);
for k = 1:length(ft) - order - 1
    warm_up = fliplr(samples(end - order + 1:end));
    samples(end + 1) = sum(warm_up .* a(2:end).');
end

%% Plot result
figure;
plot(t(1:length(samples)), samples, 'DisplayName', 'LPC', 'LineWidth', 2); hold on;
plot(t, ft, 'DisplayName', 'Original');
xlim([0 20/F]);
ylim([-2 2]);
title('Estimated and original signals');
legend;
```

### When using a cosinus

I observe a phase error between the predicted signal and the real one. This error increase with time.

[image]

### When using a sinus

The real issue appears when I change `ft = real(ft);` by `ft = imag(ft);` (so I generate a sinus and not a cosinus).

When doing this, the generated signal diverge

[image]

I think the issue is not that big, but I've been stucked on this for 3 hours now ><.

Any idea :) ?